# Selecting the record(s) with the "second" highest something

Tags: sql

I have written the following SQL commands for retrieving data from a table called `Employee`.

I was able to get the highest/maximum salary as well as the **second** highest/maximum salary, but I am having difficulty writing the same when the whole record needs to be returned.

[image]

*Select all the employees.*

```
SELECT * FROM Employee
```

*Return the highest salary. This returns the maximum salary amount which is 90000*

```
SELECT MAX(salary) FROM Employee
```

*Return the employee record with the highest salary. This returns all the records of the person/people with their salary being the maximum salary which is 90000 that is only John Henry in this case.*

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE salary = ( SELECT MAX(salary) FROM Employee )
```

*Return every other employee record; i.e. everyone except the one with the highest salary.*

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE salary != ( SELECT MAX(salary) FROM Employee )
```

*Return the second highest salary. This returns the second maximum salary amount which is 85000*

```
SELECT MAX(salary) FROM Employee
WHERE salary != ( SELECT MAX(salary) FROM Employee )
```

*Return the employee record with the second highest salary. This returns all the records of the person/people with their salary being the second maximum salary which is 85000 that is only Michael Greenback in this case.*

I am stuck in this... I tried using `HAVING` as an extra condition, but however I arrange it to specify a condition, I get syntax errors. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Window functions are the built-in functionality to do this.  In particular, `dense_rank()`:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*, dense_rank() over (order by salary desc) as seqnum
      from employee e
     ) e
where seqnum = 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a SQL Server solution but can be easily re-written using `limit N` instead of `top N`. If your database doesn't support  `window functions`, you could try this. If it does, Gordon's solution is the way to go.

```
with cte as

(select max(salary) as second_max
 from employee
 where salary in (select distinct top 2 salary -- top n is what makes this scalable
                  from employee
                  order by salary asc)) -- get top 2 salaries and sort them
select * 
from employee 
where salary = (select second_max from cte);
```

Comment: Thanks for this useful alternative to Gordon's answer.